# Galois Theory and automorphism.

Tags: galois-theory, automorphism-group

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$
Let $K$ be a field and $L/K$ and algebraic extension of $K$ $(L \subset \overline{K})$. Assume that for all $\sigma \in \Gal(\overline{K}/K)$, we have $\sigma\bigr|_L: L \to L \in \Gal(L/K)$. Show that $G(L/K) = \{\sigma\bigr|_L: \sigma \in G(\overline {K}/K) \}$

By hypothesis we have $ \{\sigma/_L: \sigma \in \Gal(\overline {K}/K) \} \subset \Gal(L/K)$. How can I prove the other side? That is, if I have $\tau \in G(L/K)$, how can I prove that there exists a $\sigma \in \Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ s.t $\sigma\bigr|_L = \tau$.

The only thing I know is: $\tau: L \to \overline{K}$ is injective.

I've seen this question before, It's very common to prove that in some books about Galois Theory, but the hypothesis that $L/K$ is algebraic is replaced by $L/K$ is finite. You can see a proof about that in the book ''Théorie de Galois'', by Josette Calais.

I could not use that proof to prove this exercise (Cause $L/K$ finite use another theorem), so can you help me?

Comment: Is $L/K$ also a Galois extension in your problem?

Comment: not necessarily, but I know that the hipotesys is equivalent to $L:K$ normal.

Comment: Consider the case $K=\Bbb{Q}$, then $\overline{K}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} K_n$ is a tower of simple extensions, where $K_n= K_{n-1}(a_n)\cong K_{n-1}[x_n]/(f(x_n))$. Any $K$-homomorphism $K_n\to \overline{K}$ extends to an homomorphism $K_{n+1}\to \overline{K}$. Do you see how ? Thus it extends to an homomorphism $\overline{K}\to \overline{K}$, the automorphism you are asking for. When $K=\Bbb{C}(z)$ it becomes harder because we have to replace $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}$ by a transfinite recursion and use things like Zorn lemma (axiom of choice).